# how to query using isodate in pymongo

Tags: python, pymongo

I have a mongodb query that works in the mongo shell:

```
db.collection.find({ created_at:  { $gte : ISODate("2015-03-01T00:00:00.000Z"), $lt : ISODate("2015-03-30T00:00:00.00Z") } })
```

I'm trying the following pymongo:

```
test_range = agents.coll.find({ "created_at" :  { "$gte" : "ISODate('2015-03-01T00:00:00.000Z')", "$lt" : "ISODate('2015-03-30T00:00:00.00Z')" } })
```

and I'm getting `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

What the correct way to handle ISODate in pymongo query?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Dates are stored as ISODates in MongoDB but, when you're using Pymongo, dates are converted to Python Datetime objects.  So, using Pymongo, your query should look like this:

```
test_range = agents.coll.find({ "created_at": {"$gte" : datetime(2015, 3, 1), "$lt": datetime(2015, 3, 30)}})
```

Comment: How to process with datetime?

Comment: can i use this in a pipeline to aggregate?

Comment: @AuturBraga can you use datatimes in aggregation?  Yes.

Answer (score 4):

Use `isoformat()`. Example `dt = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()`.

Comment: .isoformat() dates the datetime object and converts it into an ISO-formatted string. Will that work when querying ISODate fields through PyMongo?

Answer (score 1):

Below code is working fine for me

```
db.yourcollection.find({"createdAt":{"$gte":dateutil.parser.parse(str(date_time_str)),"$lt":dateutil.parser.parse(str(currentdate))},\
"status":"completed"},{"_id":0})
```

For me if date is not convert into **string** then a error message is showing "Parser must be a string or character stream, not date"